# Retrieve hub sites and associated sites using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I got this pnp PowerShell to retrieve hub sites and associated sites. Can someone please help on how to get the output to a csv with the header?
Right now it's writing to the host.

## List all sites being a hub site or associate to a hub site

```
$results = Submit-PnPSearchQuery -Query 'contentclass=sts_site' -RefinementFilters 'departmentid:string("{*",linguistics=off)' -TrimDuplicates $false -SelectProperties @("Title","Path","DepartmentId","SiteId") -All -RelevantResults
```

## Filter out the hub sites

```
$hubSites = $results |? { $_.DepartmentId.Trim('{','}') -eq $_.SiteId  }
```

## Loop over the hub sites

```
foreach( $hub in $hubSites ) {
    Write-Host $hub.Title - $hub.Path -ForegroundColor Green
    # Filter out sites associated to the current hub
    $associatedSites = ($results |? { $_.DepartmentId -eq $hub.DepartmentId -and $_.SiteId -ne $hub.SiteId })
    foreach($site in $associatedSites) {
        Write-Host "`t"$site.Title - $site.Path -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Export-csv is your friend , both for exporting listitems and custom objects : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 0):

A demo about exporting SharePoint list data to CSV using PowerShell for your reference:

```
 #Array to Hold Result - PSObjects
$ListItemCollection = @()

 #Get All List items where Status is "In Progress"
 $list.Items |  Where-Object { $_["Status"] -eq "In Progress"} | foreach {
 $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject
 $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Title" -value $_["Title"]
 $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Department" -value $_["Department"]
 $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Status" -value $_["Status"]
 $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Priority" -value $_["Priority"]

 #Add the object with property to an Array
 $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
 }
 #Export the result Array to CSV file
 $ListItemCollection | Export-CSV "c:\ListData.txt" -NoTypeInformation                       

#Dispose the web Object
$web.Dispose()
```

You can change it as your requirement.

[Export SharePoint List Items to CSV using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/04/export-sharepoint-list-items-to-csv-using-powershell.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using the below PnP PowerShell script we can generate all hub sites and their associated sites from a tenant and also all associated sites for a particular hub site:

**PnP PowerShell script to get all hub sites and their all associated sites inventory from a tenant:**

```
CLS
$userName = "Global-sharepoint2019@globalsharepoint2019.onmicrosoft.com"
$passWord = "YourPassWord"
$encPassWord = convertto-securestring -String $passWord -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $encPassWord

Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://globalsharepoint2019-admin.sharepoint.com/" -Credentials $cred

#Getting the hub site id for which we want to generate the report - those are connected to this hub site.
$hubSiteURL="https://globalsharepoint2019.sharepoint.com/sites/SPHubSite"
$hubSite = Get-PnPTenantSite $hubSiteURL  
$hubSiteId = $hubSite.HubSiteId
write-host " #####Generating sites connected a single hub site report######: " -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
write-host "Hub Site URL: " $hubSiteURL


$associatedSites = @()


#Get all sites associated to the hub site(in the above hub site)
$sitesTenant = Get-PnPTenantSite -Detailed 
$sitesTenant | select url | % {$oneSite = Get-PnPTenantSite $_.url 

  if($oneSite.hubsiteid -eq $hubSiteId)
  {

    write-host "Associated Site URL: " $oneSite.url

     $assocatedSiteObject = New-Object PSObject     
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Hub Site URL" -value $hubSiteURL
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Hub Site ID" -value $hubSiteId
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Associated Site URL" -value $oneSite.Url
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Associated Site Status" -value $oneSite.Status


     #Add the object with property to an Array
     $associatedSites += $assocatedSiteObject

  }
}

#Export the site array collection to a CSV file
$associatedSites | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\GetAllSitesAssociatedInHubSites\SitesConnectedToSingleHubSiteReprot.csv" -NoTypeInformation  
write-host " #####Generating sites connected a single hub site report- ends here######: " -BackgroundColor DarkYellow

######The below script will list down all hub sites and their associated connected sites in the tenant.##################
write-host "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

write-host " #####Generating master hub sites along with connected sites report for the tenant. ######:" -BackgroundColor DarkGreen

$hubSites=Get-PnPHubSite
$associatedSites = @()
foreach($oneHubSite in $hubSites)
{

   $test=$oneHubSite;
   write-host "Hub Site URL: " $oneHubSite.SiteUrl


   $hubSite = Get-PnPTenantSite $oneHubSite.SiteUrl;  
   $hubSiteId = $hubSite.HubSiteId





#Get all sites associated to the hub site(in the above hub site)
$sitesTenant = Get-PnPTenantSite -Detailed 
$sitesTenant | select url | % {$oneSite = Get-PnPTenantSite $_.url 

  if($oneSite.hubsiteid -eq $hubSiteId)
  {
    write-host "Associated Site URL: " $oneSite.url
    $assocatedSiteObject = New-Object PSObject

     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Hub Site URL" -value $oneHubSite.SiteUrl
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Hub Site ID" -value $oneHubSite.ID
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Associated Site URL" -value $oneSite.Url
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Associated Site Status" -value $oneSite.Status


     #Add the object with property to an Array
     $associatedSites += $assocatedSiteObject

  }
}


}
#Export the site array collection to a CSV file
$associatedSites | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\GetAllSitesAssociatedInHubSites\SitesConnectedToHubSiteReprotForTenant.csv" -NoTypeInformation  
write-host "##### Generating master hub sites along with connected sites report for the tenant ends here ######:" -BackgroundColor DarkYellow

######The below script will list down all hub sites and their associated connected sites in the tenant - ends here##################
```

**Output csv for all hub sites and their all associated sites:**

[image]

**Output csv for all associated sites connected to a particular hub site:**

[image]

**For more details please refer the below article:**

[Retrieve hub sites and associated sites using PnP Powershell](https://global-sharepoint.com/powershell/office-365-retrieve-hub-sites-and-associated-sites-using-pnp-powershell/)

Comment: Since you are retrieving all the sites in the tenant and then filtering by hubsite url...I think this method can be quite slow on busy tenants, dont you think so?