# How can I have a list of all the sites that are part of the same Hub?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, hub-site

I need to make a list of all the sites that are under a HUB.
So I'm wondering if there is a way to see a list of all the sites that are part of a certain HUB, this to better manage them.

Comment: You want only list in csv or webpart ?

Comment: Check the PowerShell code given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264357/retrieve-hub-sites-and-associated-sites-using-powershell) in question if this helps you.

Comment: @SiddharthVaghasia it doesn't matter as long as I can see the sites, at least their urls

Comment: It can also be done via REST API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152576/get-sharepoint-hub-site-associated-sites-csom

Comment: It can also be done via REST API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152576/get-sharepoint-hub-site-associated-sites-csom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved thru SharePoint online admin center URL as well as PnP PowerShell script.

**Approach 1:**

**Step 1:**

Go to the https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com url 
Click Active sites link from left side panel then we can see all active sites report in the dashboard.

**Step 2:**

Then from the “Active sites” dashboard click on “Hub” -> Filter by Hub -> then select your hub site – this will list down all sites those are connected to that particular hub site.

We will get the below screen:

[image]

Now – we can see all sites those are connected to the hub site “SP Hub Site”

[image]

**Approach 2: by exporting the sites report to csv**

From the “Active sites” dashboard click on “Export” button. This will export all sharepoint online sites in csv file to your local download folder.
[image]

We will get the active sites report as below – from there we can filter as per our need.
[image]

**Approach 3: Using PnP PowerShell**

**Script 1: Get all associated sites for a particular hub site**

```
CLS
$userName = "Global-sharepoint2019@globalsharepoint2019.onmicrosoft.com"
$passWord = "YourPassWord"
$encPassWord = convertto-securestring -String $passWord -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $encPassWord

Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://globalsharepoint2019-admin.sharepoint.com/" -Credentials $cred

#Getting the hub site id for which we want to generate the report - those are connected to this hub site.
$hubSiteURL="https://globalsharepoint2019.sharepoint.com/sites/SPHubSite"
$hubSite = Get-PnPTenantSite $hubSiteURL  
$hubSiteId = $hubSite.HubSiteId
write-host " #####Generating sites connected a single hub site report######: " -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
write-host "Hub Site URL: " $hubSiteURL


$associatedSites = @()


#Get all sites associated to the hub site(in the above hub site)
$sitesTenant = Get-PnPTenantSite -Detailed 
$sitesTenant | select url | % {$oneSite = Get-PnPTenantSite $_.url 

  if($oneSite.hubsiteid -eq $hubSiteId)
  {

    write-host "Associated Site URL: " $oneSite.url

     $assocatedSiteObject = New-Object PSObject     
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Hub Site URL" -value $hubSiteURL
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Hub Site ID" -value $hubSiteId
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Associated Site URL" -value $oneSite.Url
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Associated Site Status" -value $oneSite.Status


     #Add the object with property to an Array
     $associatedSites += $assocatedSiteObject

  }
}

#Export the site array collection to a CSV file
$associatedSites | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\GetAllSitesAssociatedInHubSites\SitesConnectedToSingleHubSiteReprot.csv" -NoTypeInformation  
write-host " #####Generating sites connected a single hub site report- ends here######: " -BackgroundColor DarkYellow
```

**Script 2: Master Report: Get all associated sites for all hub sites from SharePoint online tenant**

```
######The below script will list down all hub sites and their associated connected sites in the tenant.##################
write-host "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

write-host " #####Generating master hub sites along with connected sites report for the tenant. ######:" -BackgroundColor DarkGreen

$hubSites=Get-PnPHubSite
$associatedSites = @()
foreach($oneHubSite in $hubSites)
{

   $test=$oneHubSite;
   write-host "Hub Site URL: " $oneHubSite.SiteUrl

   $hubSite = Get-PnPTenantSite $oneHubSite.SiteUrl;  
   $hubSiteId = $hubSite.HubSiteId  

#Get all sites associated to the hub site(in the above hub site)
$sitesTenant = Get-PnPTenantSite -Detailed 
$sitesTenant | select url | % {$oneSite = Get-PnPTenantSite $_.url 

  if($oneSite.hubsiteid -eq $hubSiteId)
  {
    write-host "Associated Site URL: " $oneSite.url
    $assocatedSiteObject = New-Object PSObject

     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Hub Site URL" -value $oneHubSite.SiteUrl
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Hub Site ID" -value $oneHubSite.ID
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Associated Site URL" -value $oneSite.Url
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Associated Site Status" -value $oneSite.Status


     #Add the object with property to an Array
     $associatedSites += $assocatedSiteObject

  }
}

}
#Export the site array collection to a CSV file
$associatedSites | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\GetAllSitesAssociatedInHubSites\SitesConnectedToHubSiteReprotForTenant.csv" -NoTypeInformation  
write-host "##### Generating master hub sites along with connected sites report for the tenant ends here ######:" -BackgroundColor DarkYellow

######The below script will list down all hub sites and their associated connected sites in the tenant - ends here##################
```

**Script execution example:**
[image]

**Exported Hub and associated sites report .csv example:**
[image]

**Reference URL:**

https://global-sharepoint.com/powershell/office-365-retrieve-hub-sites-and-associated-sites-using-pnp-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

You can use PnP PowerShell to get the list of associated sites of a hub site.

Open SharePoint Online Management Shell, then run the command below to install PnP module:

```
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
```

Then paste and change the URLs of SharePoint admin center and hub site in the command below, then run it in SharePoint Online management shell:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com

# get the hub site id
$hubSite = Get-PnPTenantSite "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
$hubSiteId = $hubSite.HubSiteId

# get all sites associated to the hub
$sites = Get-PnPTenantSite -Detailed
$sites | select url | % { 
  $s = Get-PnPTenantSite $_.url 
  if($s.hubsiteid -eq $hubSiteId){
    write-host $s.url
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm very unfamiliar with PowerShell, how exactly can I run this code?

Comment: I update my reply, you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using the SharePoint Online PowerShell or PNP powershell. Their is limitation of PowerShell commands so i have to write the below code, it will take time as per your tenant's number of site collection.

To run the below script you need **SharePoint Tenant Admin rights**.

Using **SPO PowerShell**:

```
#connect to Tenant admin 
Connect-SPOService https://YOURTENANTNAME-admin.sharepoint.com

#get all hubsites in the Tenant
$sites = Get-SPOSite -Limit All 

#get all sites in tenant using the SPOPowershell
$hubsites = Get-SPOHubSite

#output array
$HubSiteassociate = @()

#file location where CSV will be stored
$fileLocation = "C:\temp\testscript\HubSiteAssociationReport.csv"

#iterating throw all HubSites
foreach($h in $hubsites)
{    
    $hubid = $h.SiteId

    #iterating throw all Sites collection
    foreach($site in $sites)   
    {
        #pulling the information for indviual site collection
        $sit = Get-SPOSite $site.url               

        #checking if the Hubsite ID match with Site collection's HubSite id
        if($hubid -eq $sit.HubSiteId)
        {

            $HubSite = New-Object PSObject
            $HubSite | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "HUbSite Name" -value $h.Title
            $HubSite | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Hub Site URL" -value $h.SiteUrl
            $HubSite | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Assoicated Site Url" -value $sit.url
            $HubSite | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "is it Root Hub Site" -value $sit.IsHubSite

            $HubSiteassociate += $hubsite
        }
    }
}

#output the restults
$HubSiteassociate | Export-Csv $fileLocation -NoTypeInformation

#disposing
Disconnect-SPOService
```

Read the complete post here: [Office 365: Get List of All Hub Sites along with associated Sites collection in a Tenant](https://krossfarm.com/?p=2653)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same requirement as me, to show all site in the hub to the users. That's simple. Create a new page and use the sites webpart.
Choose "All sites in the hub". You're welcome.